# Grid generator with custom metrics

Tags: css, grid, website-metrics

What grid generators are available that lets me customize the type of metric used? More concretely I'm displaying HTML both on screen and via a PDF generator. Because of this I would like a stylesheet based on pixels for screens and a stylesheet based on centimeters for PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Grid System Generator](http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com) there are a lot of customization options as well as different grids used. There is also [960.gs](http://960.gs/). Both have tutorials and instructions.